# É possível renomear uma tag específica?

Tags: suporte, tags, tag-específica

Ao editar a tag [laravel4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel4) notei que ela não segue um padrão de versão específica (`tag-versão`), tanto que no corpo da wiki é referenciada a tag [laravel-4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-4) que não contem nenhuma questão.

É possível (para algum administrador talvez) renomear a tag inserindo o traço que está faltando? Assim ficaria uniforme com a própria tag específica do [laravel-5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-5).

<sup><sup><sup><sup>Acho que tenho TOC, mas enfim...</sup></sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Feito. Na verdade a ferramenta não renomeia, e sim cria outra tag, e mantém a antiga como sinônima.